# Django ImageField widget to add thumbnail with clearable checkbox

Tags: django, checkbox, django-admin, django-models, django-widget

I have a model like this

```
class Participation(models.Model):
    # ... some attributes ...
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name='immagine di copertina',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

and I add the following code to show a thumbnail in the admin page:

```
class AdminImageWidget(ClearableFileInput):
"""A ImageField Widget for admin that shows a thumbnail"""

def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    output = []
    if value and getattr(value, 'url', None):
        image_url = value.url
        file_name = str(value)
        output.append(
            u'%s&nbsp;'
            u'<a href="%s" target="_blank">'
            u'<img src="%s" alt="%s" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; border-radius: 5px;" />'
            u'</a><br/><br/>%s '
            % (_('Currently:'), image_url, image_url, file_name, _('Change:'))
        )
    output.append(super(ClearableFileInput, self).render(name, value, attrs))
    return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```

Even if it worked fine for the thumbnail, the `super(ClearableFileInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)` calling is adding just the *browse* button, but it isn't showing the clear checkbox, so I cannot delete the selected thumbnail.

What's wrong with this code? How can I add the checkbox mantaining the thumbnail too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem recoding the `AdminImageWidget` as following:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import escape, conditional_escape
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput, Input, CheckboxInput


class AdminImageWidget(ClearableFileInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        substitutions = {
            'initial_text': self.initial_text,
            'input_text': self.input_text,
            'clear_template': '',
            'clear_checkbox_label': self.clear_checkbox_label,
        }
        template = '%(input)s'
        substitutions['input'] = Input.render(self, name, value, attrs)

        if value and hasattr(value, "url"):
            template = self.template_with_initial
            substitutions['initial'] = (
                '<img src="%s" alt="%s" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; border-radius: 5px;" /><br/>' % (
                    escape(value.url), escape(force_unicode(value))
                )
            )
            if not self.is_required:
                checkbox_name = self.clear_checkbox_name(name)
                checkbox_id = self.clear_checkbox_id(checkbox_name)
                substitutions['clear_checkbox_name'] = conditional_escape(checkbox_name)
                substitutions['clear_checkbox_id'] = conditional_escape(checkbox_id)
                substitutions['clear'] = CheckboxInput().render(checkbox_name, False, attrs={'id': checkbox_id})
                substitutions['clear_template'] = self.template_with_clear % substitutions

        return mark_safe(template % substitutions)
```

Note the:

```
substitutions['initial'] = (
    '<img src="%s" alt="%s" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; border-radius: 5px;" /><br/>' % (
        escape(value.url), escape(force_unicode(value))
    )
)
```

that make possible to show the thumbnail.